# ExpressionEngine: Conditional template embed

Tags: expressionengine

I'm having a bit of an issue with Expression Engine parse order and conditional logic.

I want to embed a template based on a conditional statement within a channel.

Something like this:

```
             {exp:channel:entries channel="project" limit="3"}
                      {if count >2}
                          <h1>title{/h1}
                       {if:else}
                        {embed="test/.test.html}
                       {/if}

             {/exp:channel:entries}
```

The problem is that the embed gets called multiple time from the loop.  I tried using Stash to set a variable (then call the embed if the variable was set), but it's too late or too early in the parse order.

Does anyone know of a way to conditionally embed based on channel values?

Comment: That looks fine to me. I'd suggest wrapping count in curly braces and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of EE are you using?  EE 2.9 brings substantial changes (improvements!) to how conditionals are handled.  I'm not on EE 2.9 yet but by my reading of [the 'Rendering Stages' documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html) what you are trying should work *as written* in 2.9.

Note that conditionals are evaluated in step 19 and embeds in step 21.

In earlier versions of EE embeds were processed before "complex conditionals".  See the 2.9 [announcement](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/expressionengine-2.9.0-released) and [changelog](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-9-0) for details.

Comment: This was it, I'm on EE 2.8.  Thanks!  Marked as correct answer.